# Explanation on how the sqlite DB is set up in phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

So I have created an SQLite DB in my phone gap project using the guidelines from this page: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

I just have one question regarding the function that fills the DB with data.

```
    function populateDB(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
  }
```

At the top of this function it drops the table DEMO and then creates is again every-time the application us run.
This mean it will create a new table and fill it every time because the table is removed when the table is dropped in the above sentence?!?

What is the point in removing and adding the data every time the application is opened, won't this just create unnecessary work for the device?
Is it not possible to just remove the "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO"
And only use the "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO"?

If I don't "drop table" at the top, do this mean it will add replicated data everytime? so then I would need an if-sentence or something if the table already exist?

Answer (score 2):

It's just an example, it is not meant to do anything clever or even logical. You should be able to run it without any preparation and that's what it does.

Comment: I know it is an example, I know it is not clever, I know it is not even locigal. But if I don't learn why it does what it does, I can't evolve and use better methods in the future. I will continue to use this not so clever method for ever :)

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar all the time.  During development, the code you gave allows testing for a user starting from scratch.  Then, when ready to test for a returning user, I would comment out the second line like so:

```
function populateDB(tx) {
    //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');   // Uncomment to test from scratch, comment for production!
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}
```

I never delete the line, I just delete or insert // as a quick and dirty way to toggle back and forth between the two testing modes.  For production I would leave in the commented-out line, but it could be deleted if you prefer.